# one Sufficient condition for absolute continuity

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $f'(x)$ exists for every $x \in (a,b),$ and $f'(x)$ integrable. Prove that $f$ is absolutely continuous.

How to proceed ?

Comment: I believe you can adapt the proof given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/154784/18966), for almost the same question.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: How is he writing $f(b) - f(a) = \int_{a}^{b} f'(x) dx$. We have to prove it.

Comment: isn't that just the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @Dustan: For that we want $f$ to be absolutely continuous, which we have to prove.

Comment: the version of the fundamental theorem of calculus shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part) is almost what you need; here it becomes an indefinite integral because you're not assuming $f'$ exists at $a$ and $b$, so you take limits approaching the endpoints, and continuity of $f$ gets you the result of the limit. Unless you're trying to *prove* this version of the fundamental theorem of calculus???

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: correct. But, for that we need Riemann integrability of $f'$ whereas we have only Lebesgue integrability of $f'$.